# Retry pushing messages to Kinesis using Spring Cloud Stream Libraries

Tags: amazon-kinesis, spring-cloud-stream

I am writing a producer to push messages to Kinesis stream using Spring cloud stream libraries.I am able to successfully push the data to kinesis but on the kinesis side it is failing with throughput exceeded exception.Is there a way to retry pushing these messages again and know exactly which message failed ? Also, I don't want to use KPL or KCL.

I tried the solution  suggested in the answer and this is my config:

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.producer.errorChannelEnabled: true spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.producer.error.destination: 
myFooDestination.myGroup.errors

Is this the right way to do, then how to map the "spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.producer.error.destination: myFooDestination.myGroup.errors" to "error-channel" property in the spring integration config as below?

```
<int-http:inbound-channel-adapter id="abcErrorChannel"
                                      channel="defChannel"
                                      **error-channel="errorChannel**"
                                  </int-http:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis/issues/73

Answer (score 1):

The `PutRecord(s)` request in the AWS Kinesis Binder is fully based on the `AmazonKinesisAsync` and the send to the AWS is indeed *async*. So, we can't use a built-in `RetryTemplate` feature there. But at the same time, the error of that async operation is sent to the destination-specific `errorChannel`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_producer_properties

> **errorChannelEnabled**
>
> ```
> When set to true, if the binder supports asynchroous send results, send failures are sent to an error channel for the destination. See “[binder-error-channels]” for more information.
> ```
>
> Default: false.

The channel name is based on the destination and consumer group, plus `errors` suffix: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-stream-overview-error-handling

> Also, in the event you are binding to the existing destination such as:
>
> ```
> spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=myFooDestination
> spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=myGroup
> ```
>
> the full destination name is `myFooDestination.myGroup` and then the dedicated error channel name is `myFooDestination.myGroup.errors`.

Comment: spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.producer.errorChannelEnabled: true
 spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.producer.error.destination:     myFooDestination.myGroup.errors

  Is this the right way to do, then how to map the "spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.producer.error.destination: myFooDestination.myGroup.errors" to "error-channel" property in the spring integration config as below?

<int-http:inbound-channel-adapter id="abcErrorChannel"
            **error-channel="errorChannel**"
                                  </int-http:inbound-channel-adapter>

Comment: Would you mind to raise a new SO question or share such an info in this question if you feel strong about subjects relationships. The problem that it is hard to read a code in the comments here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Customer groups comes in picture only for consumers. On producer side there is no such concept of groups. For binding to error channel on producer side use below to properties and below code to bind to error channel.

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=kinesis-stream
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.errorChannelEnabled=true

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "kinesis-stream.errors")
public void receiveProduceError(Message receiveMsg) {
    System.err.println("receive error msg: " + receiveMsg);
}
```